# Regex to mask multiple phone numbers (~) separated except last 4 digiits

Tags: java, regex, replace, masking, regular-language

I am trying to find a regex which masks phone numbers except last 4 digits.

example: `phone=9988998888~7654321908~6789054321`
Desired output : `phone=******8888~******1908~*****4321`

I tried below regex but it is masking only starting number
`phone=******8888~7654321908~6789054321`

```
^(phone)=(\d(?=\d{4}))*
```

Comment: check this.https://stackoverflow.com/a/18838946/9474700

Comment: Is your intent to only replace in strings that start with `phone=`? Or do you mean `text.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*")` is fine?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) to replace each digit in `MatchResult` with "*".

```java
public class PhoneNumberMask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String target = "phone=9988998888~7654321908~6789054321";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?=\\d{4}))");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(target);
        String result = matcher.replaceAll((matchResult) -> matchResult.group(1).replaceAll("\\d", "*"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
\d(?=\d{4})
```

See this online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yzxRES/1)

- `\d` - Any single digit.
- `(?=\d{4})` - Positive lookahead for 4 digits.

Replace with `*`.

See a `Java` [demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd318nyr)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you **only want to mask all numbers in a string that starts with `phone=` separated with `~`**, you can use a plain regex solution without a lambda in the replacement with

```java
String masked = text.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)(?:\\d{4}~)?|^phone=)\\d(?=\\d{4})", "$1*");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7aIspg/2/). *Details*:

- `(\G(?!^)(?:\d{4}~)?|^phone=)` - Group 1: end of the previous successful match and then an optional sequence of four digits and a `~` or start of string and `phone=`
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?=\d{4})` - followed with any four digits.

Comment: If it should start with phone= then this is the more precise match ++